# oAuth Access Token

Tags: magento, oauth, oauth-2.0

Hallo i am new to oAuth and i created a rest connection to Magento with that example

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/introduction.html

the php script is working and i can connect to magento. But i have to enter the admin credentials and after that i have to click the Authorize button.

now my "magento rest project" is triggered by a database. so i was searching the last hours how do i get the accesstoken without really clicking on the button? is there something like that for cli or is it even possible?

thank you very much for helping me to understand it.
cheers pat

Answer (score 0):

It would be possible if they supported the [client credential grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4), or kind of possible if they supported [refresh tokens](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.5). Unfortunately, they don't support either.

For the [authorization code grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1) that you are implementing, an authorization decision is made by asking the user if they are willing to allow your client to access their data (to protect the user's privacy). This is mentioned in the [Magento docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/authentication/oauth_authentication.html#OAuthAuthentication-UserAuthorization) as well.

Answer (score 0):

The built in Magento REST Api functionality doesn't support grant types other than authorization code grant.

I managed to use a customized oAuth2 library (https://bshaffer.github.io) (customizing the class so that it's compatible with the Zend Framework that magento is based on). It will let you choose your own grant type (in your case, Client Credential Grant).

The downside is that I had to re-create all the REST API endpoints. The upside is that it's not that hard, at least not harder than creating a custom endpoint using Magento's built in REST API functionality.